# Characters of upper triangular matrices over finite field - reference request

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory

Let $B_n$ be the group of upper matrices and $U_n$ the subgroup of unipotent upper triangular matrices. I would like some references which discusses complex character theory of $B_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$ for small $n$, say, $n=2, 3, 4, 5$ and $U_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$ for $n=4, 5$. I'm mostly interested in the character degrees and how many characters of each degree there are. But if the full character table is available, that would be great.

Comment: This is probably such a do-able exercise that there's no big-time reference for it, apart from textbooks. That is, you can just do it yourself, and thereby also be confident... But in terms of cite-able sources (so that your readers don't have to necessarily trust _you_ for this) probably some people on this site will know something. :)

Comment: Have you checked the following MO questions:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/106521/representation-theory-of-p-groups-in-particular-upper-tringular-matrices-over-f-p
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/68207/irreducible-representations-of-the-unitriangular-group
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/126932/finite-unipotent-groups-references
?
I think that for your purposes various references mentioned there are almost sufficient. It would be good to not create duplicates unnecessarily.

Comment: Thanks. That is the same question for $U_n$. But doesn't discuss $B_n$.

Comment: Passing from $U_{n}$ to $B_{n}$ is a matter of doing Clifford theory, using the action of the torus $T_{n}$ on the irreducible characters of $U_{n}.$  Since $T_{n}$ and $U_{n}$ have coprime orders, this is fairly easy to analyze.

Comment: Thanks Geoff. It would still be nice to have a reference if it exists.